# Uploading Multiple SCORM Websites/Packages (Mini Websites) To Existing Azure Website

Tags: azure, scorm, azure-cloud-services

We have a solution which allows our customers to upload SCORM (http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/) packages which are basically mini websites, just html pages and a predefined javascript interface which allows the packages to talk to our site.  This all works fine on a self hosted IIS machine as we build up a folder structure of each SCORM module within the website root and can allow the user to open each one and complete the course.

However these can be quite large, containing multiple videos, etc. and while on a self hosted machine we can place the site on a large hard drive how would this work if we wanted to migrate the solution to  azure cloud services.  I have read in several places the site must be stateless and the VM can be re-imaged at any time, does that mean that we shouldn't store anything in the folder structure that wasn't part of the original package?  Is there a way to configure a shared permanent folder for our websites to use?

Answer (score 0):

In a word BlobStorage!

As you quite rightly point out, Azure VMs are stateless so you need a single, persisted repository for your data / file, and blob storage easily fits the bill.

Without further information on precise requirements or how you explicitly need to reference these files, it's a bit hard to suggest the best way for you.  However, here's a couple of things...

1. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O00rPZBh-is) provides a quick overview of blob storage and retrieving items directly from BlobStorage.  If you scenario requires you to serve up or store files on the local machine, this might be a good starting point.
2. BlobStorage supports direct access over HTTP and HTTPS, so you may want to simply reference files directly from BlobStorage (something that shouldn't be a problem as they're web assets).  Check out the HTTP section in this [article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) for the URL format.  Note: you can also secure up these blob using SharedAccessSignatures if you want to restrict access.
3. There's no reason why you cannot use a standard VM then map a network drive using the [Microsoft Azure File Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx).  I can't say I've personally done this, I used something else, but the concept a shared resource existing in BlobStorage is very doable.

HTH

Comment: We are using blob storage for all our media however I don't think this will work for the SCORM packages as they currently rely on relative paths to navigate around and show the videos, etc. in the Html.  At the moment we are looking into having a single full VM that will be our SCORM repository but that may cause us issues with cross domain javascript calls.  More research is needed I guess.

Comment: Ah - have you looked at http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module where you can create rewrite rules for ASP.NET.  Azure servers come with the Rewrite module installed (although you might need to perform this locally) that will allow you to use relative paths.  You could be really clever and use Azure ASP.NET as a reverse proxy for your pathing issues...